# How close can coaxial cable be to electrical cable to avoid interference?

Tags: electrical, coaxial-cable

This is how now two coax cables (TV *Digital RG6 75 oHm* and satellite Internet *RG6/U Type CMR 18 AWG*) enter my home. I'd like to make a hole right next to the electrical outlet, pull in the cables behind the drywall into the hole and install a coax cable wall plate where the cables will be connected - nice and tight.

The cables are running from outside the house into a cut-through hole (you can see insulating foam). My question is: will it be safe to have coax cable lay close to the electrical one? I read that it is OK to have them laid out in a perpendicular way, rather than parallel. I presume that electrical cable runs parallel to the floor, so in this picture the coax cable "should" be in safe. I just don't want to drill the drywall in vain if this is not going to work :)

I'd appreciate helpful comments and advises. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Unless the coax is quite cheap it should be okay from signal interference.  You just cannot have low voltage inside of a box with house(high) voltage.  House wires can go anywhere, so do not depend on them being near the floor when cutting/drilling into the wall.  The receptacle might be on the left side of a stud.  Removing the face plate only should see which side the receptacle is on the stud.

Comment: Some gratuitous advice: Either, 1) use a metal junction box screwed firmly to a stud to provide a strong backing for your coax wall plate so it doesn't slowly tear itself out of the drywall. or 2) Use any method to have the terminated wires simply dangle from the wall, and make connections to them in free air, not on a plate.   If you do use a wall plate to exit, or any other grommet or whatever, this relieves it of all the stress associated with the coax connector.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have interference problems now, you should be fine putting a cable box in that location.

Use an [old works low voltage box.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N9VG9PJ) ( there is no need for completely enclosed boxes for low voltage.)  Get the cover plate that you need and the project is done.